# How to solve math equation with vertical line (|) using php eval()

Tags: php, math, eval

So I have an algorithm creator where my users can create algorithms using variables from a list of possible variables.
The algorithms they create need to be validated, so I substitute the variables with "1" just to check if they're valid and return a number without creating any errors.
My problem is that I need it to be possible to create an algorithm like

```
(0.5*(1+7-|1-7|))
```

The issue with this is the vertical line (|) which is used to get the absolute value of the equation in it. When I send this equation to eval() it returns this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '|' in controller.php(425) :
>   eval()'d code on line 1

Is there a math alternative to get the absolute value that I could use here or is there any way to escape this character so that it doesn't give an error but still does the equation correctly?

**UPDATE**
ended up taking @AbraCadaver's advice and did

```
$string = preg_replace('/\|([\d.-]+)\|/', 'abs($1)', $string);
```

Comment: `|` does not do what you want in PHP, its a bitwise `OR` operator.  Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php

Comment: thanks @AbraCadaver but i can't use php functions in this algorithm, this is user input with math operators and equations, the user won't know to write that and i'm blocking them from doing that anyway. I'm removing all text from the algorithm so that there's no funny business with eval()

Comment: You can take user's input, go through it char by char and when you detect the first |, start storing the next chars until you find another |, then you put the stored value into abs()... or something like that

Comment: `$string = preg_replace('/\|([\d.-]+)\|/', 'abs($1)', $string);`

Comment: thanks @AbraCadaver i was actually trying to avoid doing that but it seems to be working fine so i'll leave it. thank you